# make clean: Only remove files that have been generated

Tags: file, makefile, generated

With the `Makefile` I'm working on, I convert pdf files into txt files.

I've implemented a `clean` target that would remove all .txt files. However, I do not wish to delete the source files, only those that have been **generated**.

Example: 
I have following files in my folder:

`pdfsource.pdf` and `donotharm.txt`

Running my makefile would create following file:

`pdfsource.txt`

For now, my `clean` looks like this:

```
rm -f *.txt
```

Using `make clean` would not only delete `pdfsource.txt`, which is desired, but also `donotharm.txt`.

I think I could use: `.PRECIOUS: donotharm.txt`, but this is really specific. I'd like to have a *general* solution to this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be aware: `.PRECIOUS` won't help you if you run `rm -f *.txt`.  That's a whole different program: nothing in the `rm` command knows or cares what you files you may have marked `.PRECIOUS` in your makefile.  That only has meaning to `make` itself, so that it won't delete those files for you.  If you specifically write a rule (like `clean`) that deletes them `.PRECIOUS` has no impact on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list the generated files in a make variable and use it to clean only these:

```
PDF  := $(wildcard *.pdf)
TEXT := $(patsubst %.pdf,%.txt,$(PDF))
...
clean:
    rm -f $(TEXT)
```

Or, if you prefer a more compact (but a bit less readable) form:

```
clean:
    rm -f $(patsubst %.pdf,%.txt,$(wildcard *.pdf))
```

Of course, this works only if there is no `{foo.pdf,foo.txt}` pair for which you want to preserve `foo.txt` from deletion by `make clean`.

Note: using make variables, in such a case, is usually a good idea because they can be shared among various rules. Example:

```
PDF  := $(wildcard *.pdf)
TEXT := $(patsubst %.pdf,%.txt,$(PDF))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TEXT)

$(TEXT): %.txt: %.pdf
    pdftotext $< $@

clean:
    rm -f $(TEXT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: "make -nps" gives you all make's metadata about dependencies. For any intermediate file, it prints

```
filename: ...
```

So you can exactly delete such files with a generic "clean" rule:

```
clean:; MAKEFLAGS= ${MAKE} -j1 -spinf $(word 1,${MAKEFILE_LIST}) \
| sed -n '/^# I/,$${/^[^\#\[%.][^ %]*: /s/:.*//p;}; 1s|.*|${clean}|p' | xargs rm -rf
```

The first line handles use of makefiles other than the defaults (makefile, GNUmakefile, Makefile)
In the "sed" command:

```
/^# I/,$
```

... selects the zone of make metadata with dependencies.

```
/^[^\#\[%.][^ %]*: /
```

... filters out comments, implicit rules, and files with no dependencies (the trailing space). It doesn't filter out phony targets; oh well.
Finally:

```
1s|.*|${clean}|p
```

adds any explicit targets for "clean" -- what you know that make does not; e.g.

```
clean +=  tmpdir/*  *.gcda
```